# MacBook Muted, some applications still provide sound

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume

I discovered this not so long ago, when I started using Skype. I get notification sounds even though my speakers are on mute. The same thing happens with email. Suddenly there's a notification/alert sound for everything during mute. 
Is there a setting where I can disable this "feature"?

Comment: I have been noticing this for months on macOS 10.12.6, I thought I was going crazy because my iMac stays on Mute all the time at work yet I still hear the constant "ding" noise from Outlook every time I get a new email, very very softly in the background, with no other audio devices attached.

Comment: Macs are weird. When I mute mine, I can still hear it if I put my ear to the speaker, it's just very very quiet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation for this is that you have multiple sound output devices. When you mute, only the current output devices is muted — the rest are not.

The next time you hear a sound when you think you shouldn't, go to **Sound Preferences > Output** and check your Output devices one by one. It's almost certain that at least one of them *isn't* muted (a headset, for example), and that's how you're hearing the mystery sound.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that my virtual speaker (System Preferences/Settings > Sound > Output) has a software update as the macOS audio driver was reworked for Apple Silicon, the older one is unstable on new Macs, so updating/removing additional speakers might fix it too